# c# change file link path using regex

Tags: c#, regex, file-link

I have problem with regex!

I want to change the filelink ""file:\\" to "file:\" but with this solution i can't because it kill all my other slashes.

"file:\\mail\attach\2015_02\random file name" This file link is in string variable.

Do you have any idea or other solution?
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use regex

```
const string originalPath = @"file:\\mail\attach\2015_02\random file name";
var newPath = Regex.Replace(originalPath, @"file:\\{2}(.+)", @"file:\$1");
Console.WriteLine(newPath);
```

Try this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/b2f2zp)

Comment: Thx! The first solution was more simple!

Answer (score 6):

no need for regex:

```
 fileLink = fileLink.Replace(@"file:\\",@"file:\");
```

and you are done

Comment: @Zoltan No need to say thank you. accepting the answer is thank you enough, but you are welcome. Regex is a ultimate swissknife when it comes to strings. however it's focused on finding patterns in strings. You could fix this with regex too but it would be like killing a fly with a robot, state of the art AI, equipped with laser-targeting system and a flyswat, while all you need is that flyswat =)